# how to get facebook page creation date using facebook api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

my try : [https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/{mypageid}?fields={fieldname_of_type_PageStartDate}](https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/%7Bmypageid%7D?fields=%7Bfieldname_of_type_PageStartDate%7D)

Could not get any response when using this api and i am also confused about {fieldname_of_type_PageStartDate} parameter value. i tried day,month,year value according to  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page-start-date/  this fb website but it didn't work.

please suggest any way to get facenook page creation date using api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is a bit misleading, because what that page does not tell you on its own, is that those fields are part of the `start_info` property of the page - so you have to query that one.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/pageid?fields=start_info
```

This will give you a structure of the following format:

```
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "...",
      "start_info": {
        "type": "Started",
        "date": {
          "year": 2021,
          "month": 11,
          "day": 29
        }
      },
      "id": "1234567890"
    },
```

Not all sub-fields will always be set; you might for example encounter types `Founded` with only a year set, or `Unspecified` with no date info at all.

Note that this is not the actual page creation date; but the "start date" of the entity represented by the page. So it must be explicitly set in the page settings, otherwise this field will be empty.